# VBA code for automating a sheet

Tags: excel, vba

1) I have created a form in VBA and I have given connection to first sheet and when I click on the button the form is getting pop up to enter data, but what I want is, I want to assign a button in first sheet and when i click on the button the form should appear and when i insert data into the form, it should appear in the second sheet.

2) I am inserting data into sheet for only four rows and after completion of that if want to modify particular column or particular row of data how can we do that, i need someone to suggest me on this and i also request you to send me the code how to modify.

3) And I also request you to send me the code to clear the sheet if i want to enter new data.

I would be glad if someone helps me on these 3 points.

```
Private Sub cmdAdd_Click()
Dim i As Integer

'position cursor in the correct cell B9.
Range("B9:P40").Select
i = 1 'set as the first ID

'validate first four controls have been entered...
If Me.txtFName.Text = Empty Then 'Firstname
    MsgBox "Please enter firstname.", vbExclamation
    Me.txtFName.SetFocus 'position cursor to try again
    Exit Sub 'terminate here - why continue?
End If

If Me.txtSName.Text = Empty Then 'Surname
    MsgBox "Please enter surname.", vbExclamation
    Me.txtSName.SetFocus 'position cursor to try again
    Exit Sub 'terminate here - why continue?
End If

If Me.txtFuName.Text = Empty Then 'FullName
    MsgBox "Please enter fullname.", vbExclamation
    Me.txtFuName.SetFocus 'position cursor to try again
    Exit Sub 'terminate here - why continue?
End If

If Me.txtDName.Text = Empty Then 'Designation
    MsgBox "Please enter Designation.", vbExclamation
    Me.txtDName.SetFocus 'position cursor to try again
    Exit Sub 'terminate here - why continue?
End If

'if all the above are false (OK) then carry on.
'check to see the next available blank row start at cell B9...
Do Until ActiveCell.Value = Empty
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select 'move down 1 row
    i = i + 1 'keep a count of the ID for later use
Loop

'Populate the new data values into the 'Data' worksheet.
ActiveCell.Value = i 'Next ID number
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = Me.txtFName.Text 'set col B
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Value = Me.txtSName.Text 'set col C
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 3).Value = Me.txtFuName.Text 'set col D
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 4).Value = Me.txtDName.Text 'set col E

'Clear down the values ready for the next record entry...
Me.txtFName.Text = Empty
Me.txtSName.Text = Empty
Me.txtFuName.Text = Empty
Me.txtDName.Text = Empty

Me.txtFName.SetFocus 'positions the cursor for next record entry

End Sub

Private Sub cmdClose_Click()
    'Close the form (itself)
    Unload Me
End Sub
```

Comment: Your comments are really very creative :-)

Comment: Probably your best approach is to create a simple class to act as the interface between the sheet and the form. This would retain the values entered in memory until the application quits - allowing for the editing option you asked about. If you also created a generic collection class to hold the entries with a key value of the cell they reside in you could access them via the cell address to keep them straight..just my thoughts

Answer (score 2):

**A)** Place a button in Sheet one.

If you are using a form control then place this code in a module and then right click on the button and click on assign macro and then link it to the below code

```
Sub Launch()
    UserForm1.Show
End Sub
```

[image]

If you are using an ActiveX Control, then double click it in Design Mode and use this code

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    UserForm1.Show
End Sub
```

Regarding showing the data in Sheet2, in say "Ok" button of the form, link it with the 2nd sheet. For example.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")

    With ws           
        '~~> Assuming you want to write to only 1st 4 rows as you mentioned
        .Range("A1").Value = TextBox1.Text
        .Range("A2").Value = TextBox2.Text
        .Range("A3").Value = TextBox3.Text
        .Range("A4").Value = TextBox4.Text
    End With
End Sub
```

---

**B)** For this, I would recommend taking user's input and then based on that show the relevant form.

[image]

If user selects the first option then show your Data Entry Userform else show the Edit Userform which will look like Data Entry Userform but will have a `UserForm_Initialize()` which will pull the data from the sheet depending on whether user wants to edit the row or a column. How you choose to take that input is what I leave it to you. For example

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")

    With ws
        TextBox1.Text = .Range("A1").Value
        TextBox2.Text = .Range("A2").Value
        TextBox3.Text = .Range("A3").Value
        TextBox4.Text = .Range("A4").Value
    End With
End Sub
```

---

**C)** To clear the sheet you can use this code.

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Cells.ClearContents
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for the response. I have implemented the third(C) code it is working fine but when i am trying to work with Code(A) it is now showing up the form and i am getting an message as:(Cannot run the macro "Marco - Copy.xlsm'!Button1_Click'.The macro may not be available in this workbook or all macros may be disabled.)Could you please help me out with this error message, and I have an Idea for Point be but dont know how to implement it, My idea is I want to place a button with name as Edit and if i click on the button it should show the check box of the rows that are entered.Help me with.

Comment: I have an Idea for point (B)but dont know how to implement it, My idea is I want to place a button with name as Edit and if i click on the button it should show the check box of the rows that are entered.Help me with this please

Comment: could you please help me out in this.